# Avoid query timeout in oriento (node.js driver for OrientDB)

Tags: node.js, timeout, graph-databases, orientdb, connection-timeout

Given the following `node.js` + `oriento` sample code, I have an issue of running into a timeout, `[OrientDB.ConnectionError [2]: read ETIMEDOUT]`, first time I make a DB query after a longish inactivity period. Right after the timeout error the connection is somehow re-initialized and the next query runs fine.

```js
var oriento = require("oriento"),
    server = oriento({...}),
    db = server.use("users");

var getData = function(statement, opts, callback) {
    db.query(statement, opts).then(function(data) {
        callback(null, data);
    }).catch(callback);
};
```

So I have the following questions:

1. Is this the right way to go or should I call `oriento({...}).use("users")` every time I make a query rather than reusing the connection object?
2. If this is the right way, why the connection is not validated and refreshed automatically?
3. How can I manually check that I am not going to run into a timeout (i.e. validate the connection) and force a connection refresh?

Comment: I have the same issue on windows azure because WA closes the connection if it's not used within 4 minutes (configurable up to 30 mins). Did you find a more elegant solution for this?

Comment: No I have not. I currently have the solution below in production and have not had any issues ever since. Although it is a fairly ugly workaround. There is also a corresponding issue on the oriento issues list, but I think nobody has looked into this since I posted it there.

Comment: What would happen after load where multiple sockets in the connection pool would be used? You would just be keeping alive only one of them and the rest would become stale and as soon as you were under load again you would get a stale connection. I tried solving it using a retry pattern where I reinitialize the connection if I get a connection error and then retry the query. Would prefer if I could set keepAlive to true when creating the socket.

Comment: You see I do not really want to care about the sockets myself, I want the driver to do it. I also do not want to care about pooling, I want the driver to do it. My problem was not that the connection was permanently dead and I had to do something about it, but that in case of a closed socket the timeout message would take about 30s to reply and the query would not run. Immediately after that the next query runs just fine. So the "fix" is the solution for me as it just prevents the situation of running into the timeout, loosing the query and having half a min wait. It's been running for weeks

Comment: I too have the same issue.. any solutions so far for this?

Comment: I haven't checked as the workaround below works for me. I filed a bug, but cannot recall much activity around it.

Answer (score 0):

Any suggestions better than the following fairly ugly hack to keep the transport socket by pinging the DB every minute?

```
setInterval(function(db) {
    db.query("select from user").then(function(data) {
        console.log("still alive");
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}, 60000, db);
```